# Looking for simple persistent message buffer in Java

Tags: java, messaging, rabbitmq

I am looking for a simple persistent buffer as temporary storage for JSON messages in a Java application. Memory usage should be relatively constant and not depend on the number of messages in the buffer. It would nice to be able to replay messages from a point in the past. Deletion of old messages should be efficient. Needs to be able to handle 1m messages/h.

Currently my application uses a local RabbitMQ broker which shovels messages to a remote RabbitMQ broker. When the remote broker is down or not accepting messages the local RabbitMQ broker's memory usage rises with the queue length and eventually it stops accepting messages. I want to swap this out for a local disk based buffer and a thread copying messages to the remote RabbitMQ broker.

Anyone have any ideas? I have looked at Kafka but it seems like overkill for my use-case. MongoDB is a possibility but I am worried about its memory usage.

Comment: Not sure but maybe Redis? It supports pub/sub also...

Comment: redis is blazing fast but needs so much memory. check this out.  http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage

Comment: You might consider something like https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle Its designed to support over 10M messages per second but you have to rotate the files to delete them.

Comment: The app already uses Redis for other things but it uses too much memory for this

Comment: Java-Chronicle looks like it might do the job .. will check it out tm! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory usage is always an issue in any system.I am using MongoDB for production and when I compare with similar solutions (CouchDB,CouchBase,redis.io), MongoDB is really good in memory management and easiness of implementation. But I should admit , I never had a chance to test Riak more in detail.

I am storing 5.000.000 user records with 4 index fields and all user session behind a rest/web service api which uses a messaging service behind.

My messaging service uses another db instance on the same server. 
My user records have at least 20 fields and session records have just 5 fields.
My ubuntu servers never used more than 10 GB rams even with heavy loading processes.

Hope this helps to figure out.

ps: all depend on data model and how you implement your infrastructure.

Regards,

**EDIT:**

I think [this](http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongodb-as-message-queue) is a good slideshow about using MongoDB for messaging.

and a nice [article](http://captaincodeman.com/2011/05/28/simple-service-bus-message-queue-mongodb/) about MongoDB and messaging.

You can use the test code and see the results are ok for your solution.
Please don't forget to share your results if you test.

Comment: I ended up writing a persistent message queue server with the replay stuff we needed. Checkout http//qdb.io/